# Use of git reset --soft without the commit id

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

Is there any use case in using just `git reset --soft` **without mentioning the commit id**? I understand its great help when there's a commit id associated with it

Comment: Makes no sense.... it would _assume_ you are doing `git reset --soft @` which would ask the current branch pointer (already pointing to `@`) to point to `@`.

Comment: It's indeed a no-op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

Without commit-id that command does nothing to your branch or working directory.
It resets the current branch to the commit *it's already on*, *without* changing any files.

However, it does create a simple entry for git's current head in the `git reflog`, which will look something like this:

```
15bf991eb HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
```

That's not particularly useful either though.
Because there already is a similar entry for that head in the reflog; from when you last switched/reset/committed/merged/pulled/cloned.

So maybe the only use-case is for educational purposes, for demonstrating how `git reflog` entries will be created by `git reset` (without actually needing to change anything).

Comment: yeah... I was experimenting how different types of reset work with and without commit id. I came to know that this doesn't do anything to staging area or working directory. Just to concrete/confirm my understanding, I put it up. Thanks!